# Reset Node app on Azure to the default container image

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I've created a Node 14 Web app on Azure. For Publish, I chose Code (not Container). Then I've changed the default container image with `az webapp config container set`. Question, how can I revert that to the default image (which was `NODE|14-lts`)?

Running `az webapp config container set --docker-custom-image-name 14-lts` resets it to `DOCKER|14-lts`, which is not the same.

Running `az webapp config container set --docker-custom-image-name "NODE|14-lts"` produces an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have tested in our local environment(created a webapp with Linux as runtime )  below findings are based on the analysis.

If you are using docker container as publish mode then `LinuxFxVersion` value will be "DOCKER|node:14-lts" you cannot change the value of `LinuxFxVersion` to "NODE|14-LTS".

If you want "NODE|14-LTS" value in `LinuxFxVersion` in the site properties
you need change the publish mode from docker container to code mode by using the below cmdlet.

```
az webapp config set --name <webappName> --resource-group <resourceGroupName> --linux-fx-version 'Node|14-LTS'
```

Comment: So, when I specify the docker image for an app, like I did, that effectively converts it to publish mode=container, am I right? All the code deployment flow is gone?